# Changing Icons on ExpansionPanelSummary Expansion

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have an ExpansionPanelSummary specified with an expandIcon for an Add icon. Upon click it rotates which is all native to the ExpansionPanelSummary.

However on click, I want the Add icon to change into a Remove icon. This behavior does not seem native to ExpansionPanelSummary. How would I adjust?

```
<ExpansionPanel classes={{ root: "SubMenuPanel", expanded: "expanded" }}>
    <ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<AddIcon/>} >
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. Save `expanded` somewhere on state and then:

```
<ExpansionPanel classes={{ root: "SubMenuPanel", expanded: this.state.expanded }}>
    { this.state.expanded ? 
    (<ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<AddIcon/>} >) :
    (<ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<RemoveIcon/>} >) }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

i changed arrow up to => '+'
and arrow down to => '-'
first of all you should import
`import Add from '@material-ui/icons/Add';
import Remove from '@material-ui/icons/Remove';`

then in `ExpansionPanelSummary`
just 
`expandIcon={expanded === item.key ? <Remove /> : <Add />}`

Answer (score 0):

```
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const ExpansionPanelSummary = withStyles({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "#efefef",
    minHeight: 56,
    "&$expanded": {
      minHeight: 56
    }
  },
  content: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textTransform: "capitalize",
    "&$expanded": {
      margin: "12px 0"
    }
  },
  expanded: {},
  **expandIcon: {
    position: "absolute",
    left: "300px"
  }**
})(MuiExpansionPanelSummary);
```